# Converting string to int for comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, if-statement, razor-pages

I have identity set up on my Razor pages ASP.NET Core web application, and I've set the user name to V003950. A bit of backstory on my web app is that you can upload/download files, an admin can upload and assign a user, then the user logs on and can only see their files.

The id I am trying to compare it to is an integer, and the Id is 3950, so I'm trying to do an if statement like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
    {
        if(User.Identity?.Name! == item.VendorId){
            if (item.FileType == "Purchase Order")
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                    </td>
                    @*<td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                    </td>*@
                    @*<td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="Upload" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Upload File</a>
                    </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @if (item.Attachment != null)
                        {
                            <form asp-page-handler="Download" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Download">
                            </form>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
```

but because one is a string and one is an int it doesnt work. I've also tried converting the name to int, but the V at the start is becoming a problem.

Is there a way for me to remove the leading V from the if or maybe add in a .contains instead?

Comment: just convert your Integer to string and compare those two

Comment: Your UserName are  all in the style of `V`+`some number`?

Comment: I would also like to point out converting string `003950` to int will result in `3950` watch out with this conversion. It is better practice to make the int a string in the case the string can start with a 0

Comment: @N0m4n904 I tried that and I'm getting an error - Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: @XinranShen Yes thats correct.

Comment: @rbdeenk I know, I'm just testing all options atm, my last resort will be to create a new db where its a string instead of int

Comment: How do you convert your integer to string?

Comment: Have you tried to `Int32.Parse((User.Identity?.Name).Substring(1, a.Length - 1))`?

Comment: Is there any case where V003950 contains different starting numbers? like V143950
If you are 100% sure this is impossible you could remove the V using `.Replace("V", "")` or `.Trim( new Char[] { 'v', 'V' } )`

Comment: General advice: put all such deciding logic in the Controller class. It makes the Views simpler. Also if you want to add Unit Tests at some point, then the logic will be quite hard to test (or not at all) if it is part of a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UserName are all in the style of `V+some number`, So you can use this code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
    {
       var result = User.Identity?.Name;
       if(result!=null){
           if(Int32.Parse(result.Substring(1, result.Length - 1)) == item.VendorId){
              //.......
              }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the ideas mentioned in the comments, I suggest to remove the first character from `Name` using [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0), then convert it to `int` using [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) and finally compare it to the `VendorId`, like this:

```cs
if (int.TryParse(User.Identity?.Name?.Substring(1), out int nameAsInteger) &&
    nameAsInteger == item.VendorId)
{
}

// or use AsSpan instead of Substring to impove performance

if (int.TryParse(User.Identity?.Name?.AsSpan(1), out int nameAsInteger) &&
    nameAsInteger == item.VendorId)
{
}
```

**AsSpan:**

As user [madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection) mentioned in the comments, `Substring` allocates a new `string` object on the heap and performs a full copy of the extracted text. You can improve performance by calling [`AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=net-6.0#system-memoryextensions-asspan(system-string-system-int32)) instead.

Comment: This is a very solid answer. We just need OP to prove that the 2 numbers after the V are just filler, in case they belong to some other Indentifier. they might be filled and might return false since the  `nameAsInteger` might be `143950` compared to `item.VendorId` which would be 3950

Comment: Instead of `.Sustring(1)`, use `.AsSpan().Slice(1)` to avoid allocating a new, temporary string.

Comment: Or simply `.AsSpan(1)`, right?

Comment: Yes. Good point. I forgot about that overload.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your integer to string with `.ToString()`

Like rbdeenk mentioned in his comment you can get rid of the "V" in your name using

`.Trim( new Char[] { 'v', 'V' } )`

and then compare the two strings.

Comment: How would you compare 003950 and 3950?

Comment: Do make sure that the format of the A: `User.Identity?.Name` is always equal to the B: `item.VendorId`. In your case comparing `A` does not equal `B` Since the leading zeros are still there.

Comment: i would suggest `int.TryParse()` on the string where the V is removed. Since this will remove all leading zeroes. Although once again you have to be absolutely sure these leading numbers cannot differ from the actual id

Comment: I tried this: `IF(User.Identity.Name.Contains(Convert.ToString(item.VendorId)))` and it worked, only issue with it was it would show all documents that didn't have a vendor id as well. I wouldve had to add in another if statement to check if vendorId NOT NULL. It also would've return some wrong files if we had two similar vendor ids' - 003950 and 013950 for example.